# Specifying time in a SQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

I want to have a button where the user inputs the date In the format, e.g. `22 Dec 2010 07:55 AM`. But it would be great if it was in the format just `22 Dec 2010`
It should be converted to time in this format `1292984705` while trying to process it in a mysql query.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_history where date>'$time1' AND date<'$time2' ORDER By id DESC");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert the string representation of a date into a UNIX timestamp:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_history where date > " . strtotime($time1) . " AND date < " . strtotime($time2) . " ORDER By id DESC");
```

Notice that I removed the quotes surrounding the concatenated timestamps, this will perform true arithmetic on the timestamps.